# Keeping Extensions in Memory, iOS apps

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-app-extension

For iOS extensions (I'm in particularly thinking about keyboards), it seems like they have to re-initailize all objects every time the extension is pulled up. Is there anyway to keep them in memory?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for letting me know!